# Did SHOpenWithDialog API change in Windows 10?

Tags: winapi

I have a function which allows the user to edit a file, either with their default program, or choose a program using [`SHOpenFileDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenwithdialog).

I'm calling it by PInvoke in C# (https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHOpenWithDialog.html):

```cs
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "SHOpenWithDialog", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int SHOpenWithDialog(IntPtr hWndParent, ref tagOPENASINFO oOAI);
```

I call it with flags `OAIF_HIDE_REGISTRATION | OAIF_EXEC`.

Under Windows 7, it returns 1 on success.  Under Windows 10, it returns 0 on success.  The documentation claims it returns `S_OK`, which is 0, but that page was created on 2018/12/05, so I don't know what the previous documentation for it said.

What is the correct way to check the return code?  Should I be checking for either 0 or 1 return value?  Or should I be checking the `Environment.OSVersion` and checking for different return codes based on the OS version?  Can it ever returns 1 under Windows 10 as an error condition?

Comment: It's odd that the behaviour is different. The function is documented as returning a HRESULT error code on failure, though, and 1 is equivalent to `S_FALSE` which is not actually an error code. So you could check for success using the `SUCCESS()` macro and this should work on either OS.

Comment: `SHOpenFileDialog()` returns an `HRESULT`, and 1 is not a failure code, it is a success code (`S_FALSE`).  `HRESULT` error codes have negative values.  Use the [`SUCCEEDED()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-succeeded) and [`FAILED()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-failed) macros when testing `HRESULT`s for access/failure, respectively.

Comment: As for why `SHOpenFileDialog()` is returning `S_FALSE` instead of `S_OK`, that I couldn't say for sure, but it is likely related to this note in the documentation: "*Starting in Windows 10, the OAIF_ALLOW_REGISTRATION, OAIF_FORCE_REGISTRATION, **and OAIF_HIDE_REGISTRATION** flags will be ignored by SHOpenWithDialog. The Open With dialog box can no longer be used to change the default program used to open a file extension. You can only use SHOpenWithDialog to open a single file.*"

Comment: Since I'm calling it through PInvoke, that SUCCEEDED() link is really useful.  In C# that translates to HRESULT >= 0.

Comment: @BryceWagner see https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/HRESULT.html, which provides (amongst other things) declarations for `HRESULT.Succeeded` and `HRESULT.Failed` properties, and static `HRESULT.SUCCEEDED(int)` and `HRESULT.FAILED(int)` functions.